# AsyncTask returned with multi objects

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I currently have some code that is generating two objects. (ArrayList and ArrayList). The code is pulling all the data from a database and this can take a few seconds. What I am looking to do is wrap the code around an AsyncTask so I can add a progress bar around it. Do not think I can build them seperate
I cannot work out how to return both of them back to the Activity. Is there a way to run my code and give back both objects. Examples please
Thanks for your time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921244/return-data-from-asynctask-android

Comment: Why not just return a multidimensional ArrayList? If they're of different types, set the parent ArrayList<Object> and then cast the children to your appropriate type

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what are you asking, but here is the general code that I use:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    new SomeTask().execute();

    public void requestFinished(String response) {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SomeActivity.this, "", "Loading");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }       

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            // DO YOUR DB CALLS HERE
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        SomeActivity.this.requestFinished(response);
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps...